# Rails 4 has_one through with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-one-through

I am trying to establish a direct relation via has_one between two models, `Client` and `Address` as in `has_one` `:billing_address` but `Client` doesn't have a direct relation to `Address`, `Contact` does, the models:

**Client**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :contact
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end
```

**Contact**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :client

 has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Address**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :contact

 enum kind: [:address, :shipping, :billing]
end
```

So what I want is to to be able to do `Client.shipping_address` or `Client.billing_address`, the `enum` in the `Address` model is what will allow the query. The reason behind that is because the `Contact` of `Client` will have two address records, one for billing and one for shipping and I want quick access via relations

**I tried in the Client model:**

```
has_one(:billing_address, -> { where(kind: :billing) }, class_name: Address, through: :contact)
```

**But when in the view I  o:**

```
client.billing_address
```

I get a `undefined method to_sym' for nil:NilClass` And I can't seem to resolve it, thanks.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `:source` on the association since it cannot be inferred.

```
has_one :billing_address, through :contact, source: :addresses, -> { where(kind: :billing) }
```

Without `:source`, it's going to look for a `:billing_address` association on the `Contact` model.

*[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)*

---

**Update**

After reading up on the [`enum` docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), it looks like you may need to modify the scope, referencing the mapping directly:

```
-> { where(kind: Address.kinds[:billing]) }
```

I believe this is because the `:kind` field in the database is expected to be type `INTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am not getting the error anymore but seems like I still have work to do since it cannot find records      


       SELECT  `addresses`.* FROM `addresses` INNER JOIN `contacts` ON `addresses`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` WHERE `addresses`.`kind` = 'billing' AND `contacts`.`id` = 34 LIMIT 1
=> nil

Comment: I added a bit more info that hopefully helps.

Comment: Your update makes it work perfectly, thank you for your help!